# nest prisma error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: prisma, nest

I'm using prisma with nestjs.

method is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0z2u.png)

error is:

```
Type 'CreateFilmDto' is not assignable to type '(Without<FilmCreateInput, FilmUncheckedCreateInput> & FilmUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & FilmCreateInput)'.
  Type 'CreateFilmDto' is not assignable to type 'Without<FilmUncheckedCreateInput, FilmCreateInput> & FilmCreateInput'.
    Type 'CreateFilmDto' is not assignable to type 'Without<FilmUncheckedCreateInput, FilmCreateInput>'.
      Types of property 'categoryId' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Film model is:

```
model Film {
  id             Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  title          String           @db.VarChar(255)
  thumbnail      String           @db.VarChar(255)
  description    String           @db.VarChar(1000)
  rate           Decimal          @db.Decimal(2, 1)
  minAge         Int
  year           Int
  duration       Int
  isSubsRequired Boolean          @default(false)
  categoryId     Int
  category       Category         @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  genres         Film_Genres[]
  countries      Film_Countries[]
  actors         Film_Actors[]
  comments       Comment[]
  favourites     Favourite[]

  @@map("films")
}
```

Category model is:

```
model Category {
  id               Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String     @db.VarChar(255)
  parentCategoryId Int?
  parentCategory   Category?  @relation("parentCategory", fields: [parentCategoryId], references: [id])
  subCategories    Category[] @relation("parentCategory")
  films            Film[]
  tv               TV[]

  @@map("categories")
}
```

CreateFilmDto is:

```
import {
  IsString,
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsNumber,
  IsBoolean,
  IsPositive,
  Validate,
} from 'class-validator';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsValidCategoryId } from '../../validators';

export class CreateFilmDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The title of the film',
    example: 'Inception',
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  title: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The thumbnail URL of the film',
    example: 'https://example.com/thumbnail.jpg',
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  thumbnail: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The description of the film',
    example: 'A science fiction thriller.',
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  description: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The rate or rating of the film',
    example: 4.5,
  })
  @IsNumber()
  @IsPositive()
  rate: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The release year of the film',
    example: 2010,
  })
  @IsNumber()
  @IsPositive()
  year: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The duration of the film in minutes',
    example: 148,
  })
  @IsNumber()
  @IsPositive()
  duration: number;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Indicates if subtitles are required',
    example: true,
  })
  @IsBoolean()
  isSubsRequired: boolean;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The ID of the film category',
    example: 1,
  })
  @IsNumber()
  @IsPositive()
  categoryId: number;
}
```

other 15 models working properly but this one is coming with error. Can anybody help to solve the problem, please.

I've checked that typeof categoryId is same in all places
I don't have any idea

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me in Prisma. It's a red herring because Prisma type checking is a bit lacking, the actual problem is some other required property is missing in `createFilmDto`. You can either carefully check if all required properties are present, or you can replace the code with an explicit foreign key relationship (Which will reveal the actual type error).

E.g.
Before:

```
prisma.film.create({
 data:{
  categoryId: categoryId
 }
})
```

After:

```
prisma.film.create({
 data:{
  category:{
    connect: {
      id: categoryId
    }
  }
})
```